# Optimize my wordpress site to improve my pagespeed insight score

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Instead of trying everything, I am getting abysmally low page speed insight score. **0** for mobile and **10** for desktop.

It is a simple catalog site with minimum functionality. This is the reason I am unable to understand why am I getting the minimum score. I am expecting a score of at least 50 for mobile and 70 for desktop.

You can check the site - https://labhgroup.com

The pagespeed insight report - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flabhgroup.com&tab=mobile

Please provide me suggestions as to what should I do to improve my site performance.

I have contacted many developers but no one is able to solve the issues.

Comment: The PSI report already includes suggestions on how to fix the issues detected on your site so not sure how we can help you here other than telling you to try and follow said recommendations. If this is something that's beyond your current capabilities then you may want to consider hiring a developer for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use another tool other than PSI to see another improvement that you can do with your website. You might want to use [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/labhgroup.com/KdoDcUGC), from there do some tweaks or improvement and recheck your score in PSI.